# php Overriding a value in a stdClass array

Tags: php

I have stdClass array like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [IS_ProductId] => 322
    [IS_ProductDesc] => 
    [IS_ProductName] => SMARTsite&trade; Setup/1x - 0699
    [IS_ProductPrice] => 699
)
```

Suppose I am getting the above array in a variable `$product`.
What I want to do is, I want to override the third keys value which is `IS_ProductName`

I want to pass it through `html_entity_decode` but when I do so I get the error message `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

I have tried

```
$product->IS_ProductName = html_entity_decode($product[0]->IS_ProductName, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

How can I solve this ?? Any help please..

Comment: most probably `$product[0]->IS_ProductName` should be `$product->IS_ProductName`

Comment: Gerald Schneider Your answer is working for me.. Such a silly mistake.. Man it took my an hour or so... Anyways thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that `$product` is the `stdClass` object. If so, you don't need the array access notation `[0]`. You get this right earlier in the line. Your code should look like this:

```
$product->IS_ProductName = html_entity_decode($product->IS_ProductName, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

(If you have an array of `stdClass` objects, you would then need the array access notation.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[0]` from your code, as below:

```
$product->IS_ProductName = html_entity_decode($product->IS_ProductName, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

`$product` is a single value rather than an array, so the `[0]` reference is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Illusion,Yes it is possible !

You need to write `$product->IS_ProductName` instead  of `$product[0]->IS_ProductName` in your `html_entity_decode()` function.

Please check below working code.

```
$product->IS_ProductName = html_entity_decode($product->IS_ProductName, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

Let me know if still any issues.